# Перенос строк в TextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

Доброго времени суток! Возник такой вопрос: как сделать в `TextView` перенос строк? У меня есть `RelativeLayout` внутри которого лежит `TextView`. Если в этом `TextView` чересчур большой текст то он просто  идет одной строкой, а хотелось бы чтобы происходил перенос по словам. Можно ли так сделать и если да то как?

Я пробовал использовать `wrap_content` для указания длины и ширины `TextView`, пробовал `android:singleLine="false"` и `android:maxLines="2"`  но пользы это не имело, к сожалению.

Вот код:

```
<RelativeLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:id="@+id/background"  >  
  <CheckBox       
    android:id="@+id/toDownload"        
    style="@style/Checkbox" /> 

  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleText"        
    android:text="@string/тame"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"        
    android:singleLine="false"   
    android:scrollHorizontally="false" />                      

</RelativeLayout>
```

Также добавлю, что сам `RelativeLayout` — это разметка для элемента `ListView`.

Comment: Позвольте спросить: зачем вам orientation: vertical в relativeLayout, если это элемент списка? У вас checkBox должен идти над TextView?

Comment: @Rishka это не имеет отношения к вопросу. Но если вам так интересно то раньше это был LinearLayout и я забыл убрать атрибут.

Comment: я пытаюсь понять что может мешать TextView осуществить перенос:) Попробуйте жестко задать высоту TextView. Ничего не изменится? Есть еще такой параметр newLines. Попробуйте его тоже

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему вам надо использовать **wrap_content** для высоты TextView:

```
<TextView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**UPD_0:**

Коли сие есть разметка элемента **ListView** то

1) Логично назначить ширину **RelativeLayout** как **match_parent**

2) Таки да, как пишут в комментах, атрибут **android:orientation** не понятно зачем добавлен.

3) Назначить ширину **TextView** тоже можно как **match_parent**

**P.S.** Набросайте хоть в паинте чего вы получить хотите в итоге. Пока что оч. странно разметка выглядит.

Comment: пробовал, но это не сработало к сожалению

Comment: Приведите код разметки. Возможно у вас RelativeLayout не даёт TextView достичь нужной ему высоты.

Comment: добавил разметку

Comment: @JuniorThree, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Согласно документации, у TextView есть параметр

```
android:minLines=""
```

Возможно, это вам поможет.

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то помогло высталение атрибута android:maxWidth.

Всем большое спапсибо за помощь!

Comment: Вы определённо что-то делаете не так. Всё должно работать как нужно и без этого атрибута.

Comment: аналогично. Проблема решилась. На экране был GridLayout Из двух столбцов, во втором был TextView, который с помощью layout_gravity выравнивался по центру своей колонки. Не влазило 1-2 слова, жутко раздражало. проблема решилась выставлением атрибута maxWidth="100dp" - бред конечно. Но это работает. До этого как макака перебрал все возможные варианты на агл и рус стэке.

Comment: И правда работает...

Answer (score 1):

Это работает вполне

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:text="Внимание"
android:singleLine="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Убери галочку с атрибута `singleLine`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

мне помогло

```
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Answer (score -1):

Просто `android:lines = "2"` должно помочь.